# What effect does the drain resistance have on the output voltage of the logic gate?

Tags: mosfet

[image]

The logic gate is meant to be a NOR gate, but how does changing the value of \$R_{D}\$ affect the output voltage? Doesn't increasing the value of RD always make Vout lower because of voltage division. The only  exception I can think of is if both MOSFET are in cutoff and there is no current. I would appreciate it if someone could verify the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both MOSFETs are off then the output is high so, lows on both inputs produces a high on the output. Any MOSFET that is activated by a high on its gate will cause the output to become low. Sound like a NOR gate to me.

Without Rd, the output would never become high.

Comment: Ideally, high should be 5V on the output and low should be 0V. I was asking if the value of R_D affects each of the values like making 5V, 4.7 or 4.3 V, if it increases.

Comment: Both mosfets will be off when inputs are both low but there will be some leakage current that can slightly lower the output voltage. However using a really high value for Rd would make a really poor/slow NOR gate due to leakage capacitance in the MOSFETs.

Comment: So if the output is low(either input is high or both high), and we were to increase \$R_D\$. The output voltage would decrease?

Comment: If output is low then increasing Rd has no effect - it can't get lower because at least one fet is on and conducting.

Comment: I was approaching it like this: if one of the MOSFET are conducting(i.e. in TRIODE) it acts like a resistor(R). So, \$V_o=(R)/(R+R_D)*Vdd\$. Doesn't increasing \$R_D\$ then decrease \$V_{out}\$? OR this reasoning doesn't apply

Comment: OK yes, this will happen but it's likely that the MOSFET on resistance will be at least 30 times lower than Rd.